# How can I use my Samsung S4 phone functionality from my Asus Nexus 7 tablet?

Tags: nexus-7, samsung-galaxy-s-4, sim-card, bluetooth-pairing

I got two android devices: Samsung S4 and Asus Nexus 7 where the latter does not have a SIM card. I'd like to use the phone functionality from the tablet e.g. calling and/or SMS but I don't know how. I paired the device using bluetooth and I tried with an app called MightyText but that never completed the setup. Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. Download the WhatsApp Messenger App on to your tablet. It's free for a whole year, then you pay $1/year to keep using it.

By default, WhatsApp isn't compatible with tablets, but there is a work-around for that...

...[Right Here](http://www.androidpit.com/get-whatsapp-on-your-tablet)
You can also try Line, which is another messenging app.

Also...TextPlus has the least amount of work to setup (it's compatible with tablets), but it allows you to send texts and make calls. Though it's not as good as WhatsApp or Line

I've also tried MightyText, which works just fine. Not sure why it won't work for your phone...

Comment: And how does that help using the SIM-based *phone* functionality of the other device? OP didn't ask for "some way to chat", but wants to make cell-phone-calls using normal telephony and SMS.

Comment: @Izzy when the OP said they tried using Mightytext, I knew what they meant. They're saying that they want to be able to do phone stuff on their tablet.. Like they said, SMS or make phone calls. The answer I put let's them do that, which is a work around for the fact that the tablet doesn't have a SIM card

Comment: OK, you might have your point there (which I missed, not being a big fan of those cloudy stuff) ­– or OP had the wrong expectations towards MT :) So I will shut-up, and leave it to the OP to decide ;) Sorry for the interruption!

Comment: Thank you for the information. I hesitate somewhat about using WhatsApp as a carrier just to route 5 feet bluetooth or wlan connection between 2 android devices locally close, I'm going to try and install TextPlus and also another way with an external SIMcard connected via usb if compatible: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/78685/how-can-i-use-my-samsung-s4-phone-functionality-from-my-asus-nexus-7-tablet?rq=1